# UIDocumentPicker navigation bar buttons are hidden at iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I notice a problem in my UIDocumentPicker's navigation bar at iOS 11 only, the done, cancel, or edit buttons are invisible, and when the user touch it it appears i.e. The color at normal state is white, even when changing the `UINavigationBar.appearnce().tintColor`, The color only changed on touch.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor` have to work.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! The buttons are not displayed but are working when tapped..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CustomDocumentPickerViewController with black `appearance` for `UINavigationBar` and `UIBarButtonItem`

```
import UIKit

class CustomDocumentPickerViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black], for: .normal)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white // your color
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(nil, for: .normal)
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    }

}
```

Comment: can you what will be the syntax in objective c??

Answer (score 4):

For unknown reason I figured out that if you make a subclass of UIDocumentPicker using `Objective-C` and set the `[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor black];` in `viewWillAppear` func, and reset it to your defaults in the `viewWillDisappear`, it works well.

But if you do the same steps using `swift` it wont.

Comment: Awesome You are genius Ahmed working like charm Thank You :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a big fan of setting the global appearance between `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`. The appearance API should be used at application start only. You can just reset the appearance for `UIDocumentPickerViewController` only without subclassing by putting this code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and the bar buttons will return the their original blue:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
}
```

Comment: it's worked..can help me i have same problem on UIactivity view controller.. what can i do.

Comment: can you what will be the syntax in objective c.